# What's the difference between upper-alpha and upper-latin in the css list-style?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I was wondering what's the difference between upper-alpha and upper-latin in the css **list-style** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference is that `upper-latin` isn't supported by IE6 or IE7 whereas `upper-alpha` is.

Other than that, there doesn't seem to be any difference at all. They are described identically [in the offical W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-type).

For browser compatibility, see [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/lists.html).

Comment: if say I can't be bothered for old browsers. is it true to say both are "w3C standard" and both are equally acceptable?

Comment: @Pacerier - well, they're both listed there on the W3C, so I guess so, yes.

Answer (score 6):

They do the same.

[MDC says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type):

> For compatibility with Internet
>   Explorer 7 (and lower) avoid
>   lower-latin and upper-latin. Instead,
>   use lower-alpha and upper-alpha.